# Can anyone explain the following Tensorflow code? How could the function recognize the input and take it as numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

Can anyone help me to explain the following TensorFlow code? I define a simple function test_loss which takes input as a numpy array; when I call this function `test_loss(out1)`, the input is a TensorFlow tensor; how could python recognize the input tensor and take it as numpy array? I am really confused.

```
test1 = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,(1,4))

out1 = tf.layers.dense(inputs = test1, units = 3)

print(out1.shape)
def test_loss(a):
    label = np.ones((3,1))
    err = (a[0,0]-label[0,0])**2+(a[0,1]-label[1,0])**2+(a[0,2]-label[2,0])**2
    return err

err = test_loss(out1)
print(err.shape)

# add an optimiser
optimiser = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate= 0.0001).minimize(err)

init_op = tf.global_variables_initializer()
with tf.Session() as sess:
    init_op.run()
    for i in range(0,10):
        err_,_  = sess.run([err, optimiser],feed_dict = {test1: np.ones((1,4)) })
```

Comment: First, you can index tensors just as you can index np.array: `tensor[0, 0]` would be of type Tensor. 

Second, when you mix tensors and arrays in one expression and tensor is the first argument an overloaded operation of + or - or * is called and second argument (np object) is converted to a tensor object: `tensor[0] + npa[0]` is equivalent to `tensor[0] + tf.constant(npa[0])` and will produce a tensor.

Comment: Thanks @ y.selivonchyk ! I never know we can index tensors just as you can index np.array; but if we can do tensor[i,j], why do many people use functions like tf.slice to pick up some part of a tensor? Another question about overload, you mean if we do tf.some_function(tensor, npa), this will be converted to tf.some_function(tensor,tensor)? Can we do np.some_func(tensor, npa)? Thanks a lot !

Comment: Slice function would be a nicer (explicit) and more powerful way to do it. In addition, slicing by indexing, i think, is newer that slice function. And by operator overloading i mean there is an actial method in form def __add__(arg1, arg2) behind your call to simple + in your "tensor + npa". https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.geeksforgeeks.org/operator-overloading-in-python/amp/

Comment: @y.selivonchyk ! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use tensor instead of np.array in your loss function. Try `tf.constant` instead of `label = np.ones((3,1))` .